# Calling add_action on a filter hook?

Tags: hooks

I'm working with Ultimate Member plugin and while attempting to work through a modification I accidentally used `add_action` on a filter hook (not an action hook) and it still worked - as in the call back ran??

Is this a feature of Wordpress I was not aware of?
I don't see any documentation about this.

below is the code I ran. N.B no `return` either.

Here is a link to the UM docs about this filter hook [um_set_user_role](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1260-umsetuserrole)

I did a global search on all files in the Ultimate Member plugin and it is definitely not called with `do_action` anywhere.. so how did this work?

```
add_action( 'um_set_user_role', 'add_user_specific_role', 99, 3 );
function add_user_specific_role( $role, $user_id, $user ) {

    error_log( '============= UM NEW ROLE =================' );
    error_log($role);
    error_log( '============= UM USER ALL ROLES =================' );
    error_log(print_r($user->roles, true));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_action()` and `add_filter()` are essentially the same thing, hooks, and they both call the same functions under the hood. If you look you'll see [`WP_Hook::do_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_hook/do_action/) basically just calls [`WP_Hook::apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_hook/apply_filters/).

An action is essentially just a filter that doesn't return a value. If your callback function was supposed to modify the value of `$role` then that part wouldn't work, because `add_action()` won't pass the value through, but the callback will still run, as you've seen.

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked at the source instead of the notes about it. I've just learnt something new! 
Incidentally, while you are correct, the core of it is that `add_action` just calls (or returns) `add_filter` under the hood, rather than anything `do_action` does since that isn't called anywhere in this scenario.